# rvm "default" version implementation

Tags: ruby, rvm

According to the official site (http://beginrescueend.com/rubies/default/), the "default" setting of rvm controls the ruby version that is loaded "when you open a new terminal shell".

I am wondering, how exactly does rvm implement this functionality? It doesn't seem to be via .bash_profile/.bashrc (they are unmodified).

It might be attributed to my using PuTTY on Windows logging into a Debian VPS (unlikely methinks), but whenever I open a new PuTTY login shell, the following transpires:

```
root:~# rvm list default

Default Ruby (for new shells)

   ruby-1.9.2-p290 [ i386 ]

root:~# rvm current
system
root# which ruby
/usr/bin/ruby
```

That's interesting. It managed to pick up that the default should be 1.9.2, but didn't actually modify the rvm "current" data, nor the ruby paths?

Answer (score 0):

rvm must be loaded as function, no rvm ruby must be already in PATH

most likely you have issue with the first part, read https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/support/faq/#shell_login for details, but running this most likely will help:

```
rvm get head --auto
```